# Super hero story identification

Tags: story-identification, movie

It was a movie from approximately 5 - 10 years ago.

There were all sorts of crazy characters. The Devil was one of them. Another was "Magnetman" or something similar -- a character who controlled magnetic fields.

One was telekinetic and another one could cause there to be clouds / lightning.

I remember that at the end they were on a plane it started breaking up.

Comment: Could the "devil" you remember be [Azazel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azazel_(Marvel_Comics))

Comment: @Jonah I was just looking at the Wikipedia entry for that character based on the mention of him by Richard. That does look like him. However I remember him as being red whereas in the video clips from Richard he seems to have turned black.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the ending of [X-Men 2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0290334/) (also known as X2)

The man you've identified as Magnetman is in fact "[Magneto](http://x-men.wikia.com/wiki/Magneto_(Max_Eisenhardt))". The telekinetic is probably ["Jean Gray" (AKA Phoenix)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Grey), the one that looks like the devil is "[Nightcrawler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLOMdddg11A)" and the person who could control clouds / lightning is "[Storm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storm_(Marvel_Comics))".

[image]

---

Per your comment below, you're almost certainly confusing this scene from X-Men: First Class.

Which stars Azazel, an even *more* Devil-looking guy.

Comment: Yep that looks like it! But this is very weird -- the devil I remember was red and here he's black? Anyhow, I will mark this as the solution once enough time has passed for me to do so.

Comment: @Hank-R - Wait.

Comment: @Richard haha nice custom graphic! Was the devil / Azazel ever red like in the Wikipedia version instead of black? I remembered him being bright red.

Comment: @Hack-R - No, but in the film he was wielding a dagger with a distinctive red ribbon; https://youtu.be/uLOMdddg11A?t=2m8s possibly that's what you're getting mixed up on.

Comment: @Richard This was a great answer and I thought it was correct, but Jonah caught something. There was another X-man movie where Azazel was red and all of the other characters I remember were also in it. I think that's the one I saw. They both look like good films though and I can see why we were both confused since every other detail matches.

Comment: I will never call him anything other than *Magnetman* from now on.

Answer (score 4):

Richard's answer is correct, but I think you might also be remembering *X-Men First Class*. Here's Azazel.

[image]

As seen on [this wiki page,](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/Azazel) Azazel did not appear in *X-Men 2*, but rather in *First Class* and *Days of Future Past*.

Comment: !! OK Yes, I believe this is actually correct. It seems like it's almost the exact same movie except for the color of the devil so I thought it was X-Men 2 but now I think this has to be correct. He was definitely red.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5pcqKBy1H4

Comment: No plane scene though. Almost certainly getting the two films mixed up.

Comment: @Richard Oh there's no plane scene? OK then maybe I did combine them in my mind. I'm sorry. Which answer should I mark as the solution?

Comment: @Hack-R - Per the FAQ, whichever you found most helpful.

Comment: @Richard OK thank you both let me research this a bit. If I combined them in my mind I will switch the correct solution to your answer. I'm still confused tho because I did find this clip for First Class where you see the destroyed spy plane in the background. I'm about to rent the movie and figure this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HROuYFRJepQ  . Thank you both.

Comment: @Richard Yea, that's it. That's the scene. I did combine them in my mind though because Storm was in the other movie, so I will mark your answer as correct (maybe with an edit after I re-watch the films)